# How to prove that the absolute value of the second derivative of J_0(x) is bounded?

Tags: inequality, bessel-functions

> $\lvert J_0^{''}(x)\rvert < \dfrac {1} {2}$

How do I prove the above inequation?

[image: graphic]

From the above graphic it is clear that $\lvert J_0^{''}(0)\rvert=0.5$ is the maximum that the function can have. But how do I prove it?

Comment: Should follow easilty from $J_0''(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi -\cos (x\sin t)\sin^2 t\, dt.$ Looks to me like $J_0''(0)  = -1/2, $ and we have $|J_0''(x) | \le 1/2$ elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for replying. One more question though: how do I get to this expression? $J_0''(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi -\cos (x\sin t)\sin^2 t\, dt$